# Get string values after a pattern using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to get the string which are there after `$ctrl` in below html code snippet:

```
 <div ng-if="$ctrl.CvReportModel.IsReady">
                              ng-click="$ctrl.confirmation()"></cs-page-btn>
                 <cs-field field="$ctrl.CvReportModel.Product" ng-model="$ctrl.UploadedFile.Product"></cs-field>
                 <cs-field field="$ctrl.CvReportModel.Month" ng-model="$ctrl.UploadedFile.Month"></cs-field>
```

So I am trying to get output like:

```
CvReportModel.IsReady
confirmation()
CvReportModel.Product
CvReportModel.Month
```

I am trying to do it using `Get-Content` and `Select-String` but still not able to get the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Get-Content` cmdlet to read your file and use a `regex` to fetch your desired content:

```
$content = Get-Content 'your_file_path' -raw
$matches = [regex]::Matches($content, '"\$ctrl\.([^"]+)')
$matches | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Groups[1].Value
}
```

**Regex:**

```
"\$ctrl\.[^"]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Output:**

```
CvReportModel.IsReady
confirmation()
CvReportModel.Product
UploadedFile.Product
CvReportModel.Month
UploadedFile.Month
```

---

Another approach using the `Select-String` cmdlet and a `regex` with positive lookbehind:

```
Select-String -Path $scripts.tmp -Pattern '(?<=\$ctrl\.)[^"]+' | 
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
```

**Output:**

```
CvReportModel.IsReady
confirmation()
CvReportModel.Product
CvReportModel.Month
```

**Note:**
This will only return *the first* `$ctrl.*` match of each line. But since this matches your desired output it could be usefull for you.

Comment: what if I want all the matches on a line?